# text() jQuery Not permanently changing values

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure exactly if this is a caching or coding issue. Interestingly when I try to change the value of a `div` using `text()` it works sometimes and does not work other times...

EDIT *SOLVED SEE BELOW*: The issue ended up being some foul part of the code re-submitting the page a second time, thus giving the impression that the variables were not being stored, or the html()/text() was not working correctly...

```
<body onLoad="PrintLabel()">
```

And right before the closing /body:

```
$v = "<?php echo $inputbarcode; ?>";
    function PrintLabel() {
    if( $v === "") {
    }
        else {
            $indexarray = '<?php echo $final; ?>';
                if($indexarray !== "" ){
                $('#invalid').text('Added to Stocktake.');
                }
                else {
                $('#invalid').text('Barcode not found!');
                alert("Barcode not found!");
                }
        }
}
```

The `div` as written within the body:

```
<div id="invalid">Please scan a barcode to begin.</div>
```

Comment: by permanently you mean save and then reload the page permanently?

Comment: The page submits to itself and potentially stores a value within the $inputbarcode variable. So I'd like it to change the text to "Added to stocktake." if it detects anything within $indexarray and "barcode not found" if nothing is found within $indexarray

Comment: then the answer from the question above is yes

Comment: sorry, yes. I just wanted to explain a little clearer :)

Answer (score 1):

change `.text` to `.html`

```js
function changeVal(){
  $("#sample").html("New Value");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sample">Sample</div>

<button id="change" onclick="changeVal();">Change div text</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately using html() doesn't solve the issue. The page does the exact same thing...

Comment: do you have any browser error when first loading your page? I am thinking that jQuery is not loaded first in your page

Comment: no errors. watching the console jquery is loaded after font awesome and bootstrap... Could this be something to do with the page submitting and refreshing? The conditions are logically correct though it seems to revert?

Comment: Hi Jeric, I've just discovered it's a php issue. Nothing to do with text() or html(). I'm going to edit my question :(

Answer (score 0):

**Print Text into div in two method**

**Method-1**  using text()

```
$('#invalid').text('Please scan a barcode to begin.');
```

**Example**

```js
$('#gettext').click(function()
{
$('#invalid').text('Please scan a barcode to begin.');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="invalid"></div>
<input type="button" id="gettext" value="get text"/>
```

**Method-2**  using html()

```
$('#invalid').text('Please scan a barcode to begin.');
```

**Example**

```js
$('#gettext').click(function()
{
$('#invalid').html('Please scan a barcode to begin.');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="invalid"></div>
<input type="button" id="gettext" value="get text"/>
```

Comment: Hi Sumit, I've just discovered it's a php issue. Nothing to do with text() or html(). I'm going to edit my question :(

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing PHP and Javascript.  I believe what you are going for is something like this which implements jQuery's $.html() method which is what you want on a div

```
var v = "<?php echo $inputbarcode; ?>";

function PrintLabel() {

if( v == "" ) {

    // do nothing

} else {

    var i = "<?php echo $final; ?>";

      if(i !== "" ) {

          $("#invalid").html("Added to Stocktake.");

      } else {

            $("#invalid").html("Barcode not found!");

            alert("Barcode not found!");

      }

   }

}
```

Comment: Hi Jon, I've just discovered it's a php issue. Nothing to do with text() or html(). I'm going to edit my question :(

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being some foul part of the code re-submitting the page a second time, thus giving the impression that the variables were not being stored, or the html()/text() was not working correctly...

This is the code which has now been removed:

```
$('#userInput').keyup(function(e){
 if(e.keyCode == 13)
  {
   $(this).trigger("enterKey");    
  }
});
```

Thank you to all who contributed and helped solve the issue.